# CA is not listed on Autoenrollment dialogs

Tags: active-directory, certificate-authority

I've had for a long time a 2003 AD Root CA in the domain and Admins have been able to request certificates to this CA through IIS interface without the need to generate a request file using the Create Domain Certificate feature.

Recently I added a new 2008 R2 AD Root CA in the domain and the root certificate has been propagated to the whole network as a trusted Root CA certificate.

If I go to IIS on any server or my local computer the new CA is not listed when trying to create a new domain certificate.

My AD DS functional level is 2003

Both CAs are NOT domain controllers

Can someone lead me to find a solution

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you set it up as Enterprise CA?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772393(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_AS1

Comment: Yes, this was setup as Enterprise CA